# Dynamic template depending on dropdown user selection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include

Trying to use dynamic template that should change depending on user selection.

so when a dropdown option is selected then load another html template.

I like to do this cleanly and in a modular way with controller that can be uni-tested.

I have been reading this 
https://coderwall.com/p/onjxng/angular-directives-using-a-dynamic-template

Others include using 
`ng-include` to load the template

Anyone knows of better way to implement?

Comment: Any other ideas with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $templateCache and $compile in your directive. It is not always a better way, depending on what you want to achieve.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    $templateCache.get('yourtemplate.html').then(function(tmpl) {
        element.html(tmpl);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    });
}
```

You get the idea: you can also have a directive acting as a proxy to other directives by not using $templateCache and adding directly to your element the markup for another directive (and compiling it).